# What's messing with my default input language?

Tags: windows-7, boot-camp, input-languages

## The Problem

Why is my input language set to `NL` (=Dutch) every time I open an application, despite the default input language setting?

## Background

I have a Windows 7 system with an English (US) interface language. I do most of my typing in English, but occasionally I need to type in Dutch.

For this reason, my language bar is configured to contain the following languages and keyboard layouts:

- English (United States)

  - United States International
  - United States International (Apple) **<-- default input language**
- Dutch (Netherlands)

  - United States International
  - United States International (Apple)

Since the computer is a laptop that I often use on a stand I often switch between two keyboards:

- The internal keyboard (US international layout)
- An aluminum Apple keyboard (US international layout)

For the Apple keyboard, I installed the BootCamp drivers and software (like [so](http://blog.danrashid.com/post/26809751534/installing-apple-keyboard-drivers-on-windows)), which enable me to use the Apple-style multimedia keys (which are actually F-keys).

N.B.: The computer is *NOT* an Apple laptop. I'm just using Apple drivers for the Apple keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

There is a key shortcut to change between languages. It is left [ALt]+[Shift].

You can deactivate or change this shortcut under
Control Panel->Region and Language->Keyboards and Languages->Change Keyboard->Advanced Keyboardsettings.

This is a free translation from my German installation and might be different in original English Windows.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, but it does not address the real problem.